# How can I get a video to always fill hero?

Tags: html, css

I have a client that wants a video as the first thing they see in a hero section (I don't think it's a good idea, but I'm not going to fight with them anymore on it).

My issue is that I can't get it to properly fill the hero area on resizing. In 1080 res it looks fine, but it's not responsive. And with the video having text in it, it needs to be seen. Is there anything at all that can be done to solve this problem?

Here's the site: https://powertrakgrow.com/

**HTML**

```
<div class="home-hero container-fluid p-0">
<div id="heroCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- <div class="background-overlay"></div> -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="hero-inner-content offset-md-0 col-md-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-10 wow animated fadeInLeft">
                <video muted="" autoplay="" class="wow fadeIn animated">
                    <source src="/media/PowerTrakGrow-LED-Agri-Grow-Lighting.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home-hero video {
left: 50%;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
/* width: 100%; */
z-index: 5; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your css and added the following to your code:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Let me know if this works for you.

```css
.home-hero video {
left: 50%;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
/* width: 100%; */
z-index: 5; 
}
```

```html
<div class="home-hero container-fluid p-0">
<div id="heroCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- <div class="background-overlay"></div> -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="hero-inner-content offset-md-0 col-md-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-10 wow animated fadeInLeft">
                <video controls>
                      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. That's something I've tried but it just shrinks it and doesn't fill

Comment: Have you checked the width/height of the divs outside of your video element? - What this above code suggests is that the `video` element will take 100% width/height of its container.

Comment: I've tried removing and rebuilding things. But this is what I'm getting now: https://powertrakgrow.com/

Comment: In your question, if you update to include the additional CSS that goes with the rest of your code it may be easier to help.